# how to interpret Jmeter thread configuration

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to stress test a web application which is composed of login,view page,other pages and log out. The full flow contains 14 request and I have created 300 users to complete the flow.

I have the following Thread Group configuration:

[image: Thread Group config]

According to the online resources since I have 300 users and the ramp up period is 6, for each 1 second there will be 50 thread added. Therefore all the 300 thread will be up and running after 6 second.

So can I conclude that after 6 second Jmeter will have 300 active thread accessing the website at the same time?

My second question is when I execute the load test of more than 100 users when I view the Result Tree Listener in the Sampler Result tab the following error is triggered only for js and css files but when I open the response data tab for that request it is displayed correctly.

```
Response code: 200
Response message: Embedded resource download

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException message:Non HTTP response message: Remote host closed connection during handshake,
```

Is it a performance issue of my website or Jmeter cannot download all the js/css files?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. With regards to your Threads configuration, the actual concurrency will depend on your application response time. JMeter acts as follows:

   - Each 1 second JMeter will start 50 users
   - Each of 50 users will start executing your 14 requests upside down
   - When a user will finish executing all requests it will be shut down

   So given your application average response time for all 14 requests is > 500 ms you should have 300 concurrent users. You can always check how many users were online using [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) listener. See [JMeter Test Results: Why the Actual Users Number is Lower than Expected](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-test-results-why-actual-users-number-lower-expected) article for more detailed information on the topic
2. Too little information to provide the answer check *jmeter.log* and your application under test logs for any clues. One thing is obvious: you  should definitely NOT be running JMeter in GUI mode especially with View Results Tree listener enabled as it is too resource intensive and side effects might be unpredictable. So repeat your test in [non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) with all listeners disabled and if the issue will remain - inspect log files.